# json expressions to get the exact filepath

Tags: json

The JSON Data is as below

```
{"ServerFiles": [
   {"filepath": "in/b1_30102017d.ini"},
   {"filepath": "in/b1_30102017d.log"},
   {"filepath": "in/b1_30102017d.txt"},
   {"filepath": "out/b1_30102017d.log"},
   {"filepath": "out/b1_30102017d.csv"}
]}
```

I want to get the the path of ini file. This works

```
$.ServerFiles[*].filepath[0].
```

But the file varies on windows and linux, that means $.ServerFiles[*].filepath[0] returns csv file on windows and not ini file. On linux the same $.ServerFiles[*].filepath[0] returns ini file, so I don't want to hardcode with $.ServerFiles[*].filepath[0]. Is there any other JSON expressions to retrieve ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the json in the following way:

```
a = {"ServerFiles": [
     {"filepath": "in/b1_30102017d.ini"},
     {"filepath": "in/b1_30102017d.log"},
     {"filepath": "in/b1_30102017d.txt"},
     {"filepath": "out/b1_30102017d.log"},
     {"filepath": "out/b1_30102017d.csv"}
    ]}
for(i=0;i<a['ServerFiles'].length;i++){
    if(a["ServerFiles"][i]["filepath"].indexOf('.ini')!== -1)
        {
          return a["ServerFiles"][i]["filepath"];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Jayway JsonPath implementation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), the code below should work :

```
$.ServerFiles[?(@.filepath =~ /.*ini/i)]
```

**[]** is a subscript operator. XPath uses it to iterate over element collection.

**?()** applies a filter expression on the JSONPath expression

**@** is the current element

Comment: Hi thank you..but it gives the following exception [ERROR:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported operator =
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported operator =
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.eval.ExpressionEvaluator.eval(ExpressionEvaluator.java:65)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.ArrayEvalFilter.isMatch(ArrayEvalFilter.java:90)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.ArrayEvalFilter.filter(ArrayEvalFilter.java:69)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.PathTokenFilter.filter(PathTokenFilter.java:50)]